# Can't load images from project during vs2012 load test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mstest, load-testing, performance-testing

I'm trying to load test my WCF service from Visual Studio 2012 with a Web Performance and Load Test Project. I added a Unit Test file as shown below and execute them with a Load Test. Everything seems to work fine except for populating an image byte[] in my test object.

Unit Test

```
    [TestMethod, TestCategory("WCF - Primary Tests")]
    public void EventItem_Insert()
    {
        //Arrange
        var service = new EventServiceReference.ServiceContractClient();
        var item = UnitTestHelpers.EventItemFactory(Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid());
        Debug.WriteLine(item.Data.Length.ToString());

        //Act
        Guid pk = service.SaveEventItem(item);

        //Assert
        Assert.AreNotEqual(Guid.Empty, pk, "The key returned is empty");
    }
```

Snippet that calls the image load routine from the EventItemFactory.

```
EventItem.Data = (byte[])LoadTestImageFromProject();
```

Code where the issues is.  This works when I run the unit test from the Test Explorer but throws an invalid parameter when called from the Load Test.

```
    public static byte[] LoadTestImageFromProject()
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string file = Path.Combine(fileInfo.DirectoryName, @"Assets\bg.JPG");

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(file);

        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        byte[] byteArray = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bmp, typeof(byte[]));

        return byteArray;
    }
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: where is LoadTestImageFromProject ?

Comment: @Cybermaxs - LoadTestImageFromProject is in the third code block.  I refactored it to include all the the file IO code.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to reference files from my project during a load test by I did find a good workaround.

I added the images to a resource file and that worked perfectly.

It had something to do with how virtual users are handed in a test, the resource file is available but project artifacts are not.